# Hide Certain Values from an Apache Solr Facet

Tags: search

I have some Apache Solr facet blocks i'd like to filter certain values from. For example if a facet contains the values:

Filter by letter:
 - a (6)
 - b (4)
 - c (2)

I want to hide the facet "c" so visitors won't be able to use it as a filter. Is it possible? i'm ok with editing/creating modules and also it would be okay a solution that uses CSS to hide the row from view (which was my first thought but then i realized there isn't a unique identifier for facet values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept looking for a solution on the internet after posting this question and i have discovered this module:  https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_bonus which does exactly what i need

Comment: You should select this as the correct answer once the system allows you to do so.

Comment: Yes i was planning to, it'll require 2 days, thanks for the reminder